# Youtube API v3 in a .NET 2.0 application

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-data-api

I want to upload videos to Youtube from a .NET 2.0 application. Unfortunately, the [Youtube API v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/) requires .NET Framework 4.

Is there any way to interact with Youtube from a .NET 2.0 application, other than implementing the Youtube API manually?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is incorrect.

The [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) is a rest API and only requires that you can make a HTTP post or HTTP get in order to send information to the API.

The Google .net client library supports .net framework 4.5 and 4.0 the nugget package

> PM> [Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/)

Is part of the Google .net client library.

That being said it is possible to use create a .Net framework 2.0 application that sends data to the YouTube API. You just have to code it yourself you cant use the Google .net client library.

**Tip:**

Don't be afraid of coding it yourself.  The hardest part is the authentication.  This should get you started [Google 3 legged Oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)